# How to properly access objects in array using .forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For a quiz I was given an array with objects inside :

```
var donuts = [
{ type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
{ type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
{ type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
{ type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];
```

and my job was to iterate through the objects in the array using the .forEach method. Well I basically hacked it and made an iteration variable to help me use an index to access each object.

```
var i = 0;
donuts.forEach(function(donutSummary) {

var donut = donuts[i].type;
var cost = donuts[i].cost;

console.log(donut + " donuts cost $" + cost + " each");
i = i + 1;
});
```

on the top of my code I declared and assigned a variable, i, for my index. I know there has to be a better way to access the objects in this array.

> Can anyone tell me what is the proper way to do this without using an iteration variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the function provided to `forEach`, its first argument is the current item being iterated over. The function will be called for each item in the array, so you just need to access the properties of each `donut` and `console.log` them. See [MDN docs on forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
const donuts = [
  { type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];

donuts.forEach(({ type, cost }) => console.log(`${type} donuts cost $${cost} each`));
```

Or, if you can't use destructuring and ES6 syntax:

```js
var donuts = [
  { type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];

donuts.forEach(function(donut) {
  console.log(donut.type + ' donuts cost $' + donut.cost + ' each')
});
```

Comment: Thank you for providing both ways of writing my scenario. So deconstruction is used for simplification?

Comment: Yes, destructing makes for less syntax noise, so it's often preferable - if you only need to access some particular properties of an object and don't need the whole object, use destructuring to extract the properties into variables rather than use an object whose only purpose is to be decomposed later.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Use `donutSummary` in place of `donuts[i]`

```
donuts.forEach(function(donutSummary) {

     var donut = donutSummary.type;
     var cost = donutSummary.cost;

     console.log(donut + " donuts cost $" + cost + " each");
});
```

For reference, [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Ah thank you! That makes sense so the objects being iterated can be accessed through the function parameter. I upvoted, and will accept your answer when I am permitted.

Comment: Yes. Additionally, if you need index, you can use the second parameter of the function for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

where currentValue is the current object in the array, index is the `index` of the object in array. In this case the purpose of `i` will be served by the index, so no need to increment it.

Any parameter which is inside this syntax `[, paramterName ..` is optional parameter for example `[, index` is optional

```js
var donuts = [{
    type: "Jelly",
    cost: 1.22
  },
  {
    type: "Chocolate",
    cost: 2.45
  },
  {
    type: "Cider",
    cost: 1.59
  },
  {
    type: "Boston Cream",
    cost: 5.99
  }
];


donuts.forEach(function(donutSummary, index) {
  console.log(donutSummary.type + " donuts cost $" + donutSummary.cost + " each");
});
```